# Applying type to a type constructor in macro throws exception

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, type-constructor

Consider the following simple macro fragment:

```
val lstConstructor = weakTypeTag[List[String]].tpe.typeConstructor
println(c.typecheck(tq"$lstConstructor[String]", mode = c.TYPEmode))
```

This seemed to be pretty straightforward piece of code fails with the following no that informative exception:

```
[error] scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: Any does not take type parameters
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$3(Typers.scala:44)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$2(Typers.scala:38)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.doTypecheck$1(Typers.scala:37)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.typecheck(Typers.scala:51)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.typecheck$(Typers.scala:32)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.typecheck(Context.scala:18)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.typecheck(Context.scala:18)
```

What is the right way to aoply a type argument to a type constructor?

**UPD**:

Manually specifying hardcoded name of the type constructor as

```
println(c.typecheck(tq"List[String]", mode = c.TYPEmode))
```

works perfectly fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to undocumented land of untyped compiler guts.

The quasiquote `tq"List[String]"` makes the following tree:

```scala
AppliedTypeTree(Ident(TypeName("List")), List(Ident(TypeName("String"))))
```

Notice that the first parameter is not a `Type`, it's an `Ident`. So your quasiquote, `tq"$lstConstructor[String]"`, silently replaces the unappropriately typed tree with an empty `TypeTree()`:

```scala
AppliedTypeTree(TypeTree(), List(Ident(TypeName("String"))))
```

I'm pretty sure that is equivalent to `Any`, so you get the error.

---

Now, to get an `Ident` out of a `Type`, you can use `.typeSymbol` method (though idents don't have type param info, it doesn't matter whether you did `.typeConstructor` before or not). This should work:

```scala
c.typecheck(tq"${lstConstructor.typeSymbol}[String]", mode = c.TYPEmode)
```

Code on Scastie (using runtime universe) [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gx2g5yWPTcSc0K9dyVlrdg).

Comment: Thanks much. Was scratching my head around this issue for almost the whole day. Thank you.